# iOS 6, MPMoviePlayer, and autorotation

Tags: ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller, autorotate

Not really a question, more of documenting an observation:

In iOS6/Xcode 4.5, if one sets up the app with the window.rootViewController attribute set, the root view controller implementing a `shouldAutorotate` method returning NO, and nothing else, autorotation will be disabled in the entire app *except* in MPMoviePlayerViewController (and possibly some other similar classes).  (Or at least this is the behavior observed in the simulator.)  This is the behavior we wanted, but it's surprising, and may not be the behavior that is desired by others.

Does anyone know why this is, or how one might control it (if desired)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer for this is that Apple expects videos to be in a wider screen format (at least wider than portrait provides), so they are overriding your request to prevent screen rotation. I'm also guessing that once you close the video player out of widescreen mode that your app goes back to the desired rotation.